# Flutter - Layout problem using Column/Expanded/ListView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm pretty new to Flutter and I can't seem to solve this issue.

I want to display a ListView of my custom card-like Ink containers and have pretty much achieved it. However, the ListView extends behind my Text widget (the previous item in the column) when I scroll down:

[Expanded widget behind text widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zIit.png)

Look behind the "Gallery" text when scrolling:
[Animated GIF showing undesired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DRQz.gif)

I would like my ListView widget to scroll without the containers displaying behind the "Gallery" text.

I have tried without an Expanded widget (ListView.builder() directly under the Column children) but I get this error message in the Debug console:

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderRepaintBoundary#8dc77 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1702
> pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was
> Column

And the list does not display at all.

Here's my code:

```
class Gallery extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<_ChallengeCard> challengestest = [
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #1', subtitle: 'Completed on 13/11/1978'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #2', subtitle: 'Completed on 12/18/2043'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #3', subtitle: 'Current challenge'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #4', subtitle: 'Locked'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #5', subtitle: 'Locked'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #6', subtitle: 'Locked'),
    _ChallengeCard(title: 'Challenge #7', subtitle: 'Locked'),
    ];

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Text(
                'Gallery',
                style: GoogleFonts.alexBrush(fontSize: 55),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: challengestest.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: (){},
                        child: challengestest[index]
                      ),
                    );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And some additionnal classes so that you can see the specific content of the ListView item (but I doubt they have anything to do with the issue):

```
class _ChallengeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  _ChallengeCard({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Ink(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF11001A),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.star,color: Colors.white, size: 40.0,),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children:<Widget>[
              Text(
                '$title',
                style: GoogleFonts.lora(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              Text(
                '$subtitle',
                style: GoogleFonts.lora(fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The class "gallery" is called from the main.dart file (which is why there is a bottom navigation bar in the whole app), but I haven't included it since it is not relevant to the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what the undesired behavior you are describing is going from the image, and it's compounded by the idea that the code you provided would not display the widget shown. Perhaps if you provided a gif rather than a static image that showed the undesired behavior?

Comment: @Abion47 I have added a GIF to show the undesired behavior as well as more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using the AppBar widget instead of a Text widget for the "Gallery" title.

The Scaffold does not contain a Column widget anymore, only a ListView.Builder:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: challengestest.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: (){},
                      child: challengestest[index]
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
    );
  }
```

The text "Gallery" has been moved as a heavily modified AppBar with a Stack widget to retain its appearance:

```
   Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
            "assets/images/bgpurple.jpeg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(85.0),
            child: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              centerTitle: true,
              flexibleSpace: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    _myPageTitles[_selectedIndex],
                    style: GoogleFonts.alexBrush(
                      fontSize: 45, 
                      color: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your text scroll also by wrapping your widget in a single child scroll view

```
   ...

   SingleChildScrollView(// add a scrollview
                child: 
              Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                    'Gallery',
                 style: GoogleFonts.alexBrush(fontSize: 55),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ), 
                    //remove the expanded widget
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, // make shrikwrap true
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // add this physics so it won't scroll
                        itemCount: challengestest.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return Container(
                        ... // rest of your code here
);}
),
]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This does work well to make the text scroll with the cards, but I'm looking to keep the text static like it is right now. I just don't want the boxes to appear behind the text when scrolling up (like shown in the GIF).